# I get Site/Fmwk Approval denied for my associated domain on my iOS app

Tags: ios, applinks, associated-domains

I have an iOS app which it associated domain worked before, I just added a new app ID to the applinks json file but after that the associated domain on my app stopped working.

after some debugging, I found out the Site/Fmwk Approval is denied on Sysdiagnose log file.

I attached both my applinks config and log file results.

sysdiagnose log:

[image]

applinks json:
[image]

I don't know if it's the Nginx config issue or the applinks json file issue.

Note1: my json file is located here => My-Website.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

Note2: my json file has no prefix.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3155-debugging-universal-links#)?  It seems the CDN can't access your site file.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, my website is public and everything worked a couple of days before…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing the "appID" format from array to object.

Also, the bottom code added to the NGINX:

```
location ~ /.well-known/apple-app-site-association {
     default_type application/pkcs7-mime;
}
```